# ¿Como organizar grupos de un tamaño especifico aleatoriamente de una lista general equitativamente?

Tags: java, array, bucles, ordenamiento, random

Como lograr que de un arreglo de Strings se creen arreglos de menor tamaño en el cual cada uno contiene una cantidad "n" de elementos. Lo ideal es que la distribución de los elementos dentro de los arreglos de menor tamaño sea equitativamente.

Por ejemplo, tengo este arreglo de 10 strings y pongo que se hagan 10 arreglos de menor tamaño (de tamaño 5).
-Juan
-Ana
-Luis
-Sara

- etc...

La idea es que estos nombres aparezcan un numero determinado de veces pero similar a la misma cantidad de veces de los demás nombres.

Aqui va mi codigo:

```js
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
public class Organizador {
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*** MODULO CAPTURA ***/
       Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
       System.out.println("Ingrese el aforo del aula: ");
       int aforo = scan.nextInt();
       //System.out.println("Ingrese la fecha de inicio de la clase (dd/mm/yyy): ");
       //Date clase = new Date();
 
        System.out.println("Ingrese el número de estudiantes: ");
        int size = scan.nextInt();
        String[] estudiantes = new String[size];
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
            System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del estudiante: " +(i+1));
            estudiantes[i]=scan.next();
        }
        System.out.println("Ingrese el número de listas que desea crear: ");
        int numeroListas = scan.nextInt(); 
        for(int i = 0; i<numeroListas;i++){
            String[] listafinal = organizarRandom(estudiantes, aforo);
             System.out.println("Lista asistencia semana "+(i+1)+ ":");
 
             for(int j=0; j<aforo; j++){
           System.out.println(listafinal[j]);
       }
        }
 
 
 
    }
     /*** MODULO ACTUADOR ***/
    public static String[] organizarRandom(String[] array, int n) {
 
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(array.length);
    for (String i : array)
        list.add(i);
    Collections.shuffle(list);
 
    String[] answer = new String[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        answer[i] = list.get(i);
 
    return answer;
 
}
}
```

PD: Mi codigo logra crear las listas pero no las crea equitativamente, por ejemplo, un nombre "x" aparece en todos los mini-arreglos, mientras que otro nombre "y" aparece solo en un mini-arreglo.

Comment: hola podrias poner un ejemplo mas claro? lo que tengo entendido es que lo que debe hacer el arreglo es digamos meto pepipto , juana , tomas y debe retornar pepito pepito pepito juana juana juana tomas tomas tomas no entiendo

Answer (score 0):

tu lista final debe estar fuera del for para que pueda coger los datos aleatorios que indiques, lo siguiente es desordenar ese arreglo que te genera tu método, por que si no va a parecer que el mismo arreglo se repite tantas veces como indique la cantidad de mini arreglos que quieres, para ello le agregue un método que desordena aleatoriamente un arreglo de String en base a sus índices, el programa final seria así:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.stream.IntStream;

    public class Organizador {
     
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            /*** MODULO CAPTURA ***/
           Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
           System.out.println("Ingrese el aforo del aula: ");//indica el tamaño del arreglo
           int aforo = scan.nextInt();
           //System.out.println("Ingrese la fecha de inicio de la clase (dd/mm/yyy): ");
           //Date clase = new Date();
     
            System.out.println("Ingrese el número de estudiantes: ");//grupo de String
            int size = scan.nextInt();
            String[] estudiantes = new String[size];
            for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
                System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del estudiante: " +(i+1));
                estudiantes[i]=scan.next();
            }
            System.out.println("Ingrese el número de listas que desea crear: ");
            int numeroListas = scan.nextInt();
            String[] listafinal =organizarRandom(estudiantes,aforo); //tiene 3 elemntos


            for(int i = 0; i<numeroListas;i++){
                 System.out.println("Lista asistencia semana "+(i+1)+ ":");

                  Arrays.stream(mejora(0,aforo-1,listafinal)).forEach(System.out::println);
                         
          }
      }
     
         /*** MODULO ACTUADOR ***/
       public static String[] organizarRandom(String[] array, int n) {
     
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(array.length);
        for (String i : array)
            list.add(i);
        Collections.shuffle(list);
     
        String[] answer = new String[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            answer[i] = list.get(i);
     
        return answer;


    }
        //metodo de ordenamiento indice aleatorio String
       public static String[] mejora(int inicio,int fin,String[]arreglo){

           int[] numerosAleatorios = IntStream.rangeClosed(inicio, fin).toArray();
           String[]temporal=new String[arreglo.length];
             //desordenando los elementos
            Random r = new Random();

            String[]temp=new String[fin+1];
            for (int i = numerosAleatorios.length; i > 0; i--) {
             int posicion = r.nextInt(i);
            int tmp = numerosAleatorios[i-1];
            numerosAleatorios[i - 1] = numerosAleatorios[posicion];
             numerosAleatorios[posicion] = tmp;

            }

            for (int j=0;j<arreglo.length;j++) {
                temporal[j]=arreglo[numerosAleatorios[j]];
            }
            
             return temporal;

       }

    }
```